# скрыть checked элементы по нажатию на кнопку в jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть todoлист который добавляет элементы с чекбоксами.Нужно написать кнопку при нажатии которой checked задачи скрываются.Не могу понять как вешать обработчик через кнопку на проверку всех чекбоксов

```
$(".done").click(function(){
$('input:checkbox').function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).parent().css('display', 'none');
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.done').click(function(){
  $(this).parents('.todo-list').find('input:checkbox:checked').hide();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="todo-list">
  <h2>todo list</h2>
  <input type="checkbox" checked />
  <input type="checkbox" checked />
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" checked />
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <button class="done">Скрыть готовые</button>
</div>
```